# BigQuery json special characters UI export issue

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm having trouble saving BigQuery table data having special characters as json with the proper encoding. This issue is only via the UI. When I save from the CLI the character encoding is proper. In the table the data is correctly encoded. I'm just clicking 'Save Result' and save as JSON local file. While loading data to the table the data was UTF-8 and properly encoded too. Sample special char: Bié

How to save table data with special characters from the UI correctly? I can use cli but its easier to use the UI if I can get this to export correctly.

[image]

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the same. In your prints I see that you are opening the two exports in different Text Editors. Maybe the problem is on the editor?

Comment: You are spot on. After spending hours and hours figured it to be a setting with all my editors. The first editor screen was on the server. Second was on my device. But all my device editors were not rendering special characters so I thought it was an export issue. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, I could not reproduce the same problem. Since the results returned by the `BigQuery` **Console** and **CLI** should be the same I suggested that this could be a problem in the text editor which was confirmed.